# Solr 5.4 fq: search returns empty and nonempty fields

Tags: search, solr, solrcloud

I have couple of fields in solr. when i search for a value in particular field like fq, mf_name_t:"value to search" it returning the fields with result and empty value. But if i provide mf_name_t:"value", whic is only one word it is showing the accurate result.

Comment: The stored value may differ from which content has been indexed. If you're only giving `&fq="value to search"` in your query, the default search field will probably be used (by default: `_text_`), which probably isn't stored. Use an explicit field and value instead (`field:"value to search"`)

Comment: i have a field called mf_name_t, i provided for fq, mf_name_t:"value to search". If i have more than one word to search it shows fields with empty result.